# UICollectionViewLayout. Where are all my items?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When I implement UICollectionView without a custom layout object, all 16 of my reusable cells appear.  That is, I have 1 section with 16 items in that section.  When I create a custom layout object, only 1 cell appears.  If I change # of sections to 5, then 5 cells appear.  Why does the collectionView draw sections when using a layout object, and items when using the default grid????  Am I missing something?

I subclass UICollectionViewLayout here:

```
 static NSString * const kPadLayoutType = @"gridPads";

 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
 {
     self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
     if(self) {
         [self setup];
     }
     return self;
 }

 - (void)setup
 {
     self.itemInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(22.0f, 22.0f, 13.0f, 22.0f);
     self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(125.0f, 125.0f);
     self.interItemSpacingY = 12.0f;
     self.numberOfColumns = 4;
 }

 # pragma mark _____Layout

 - (void)prepareLayout
 {
     NSMutableDictionary *newLayoutInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     NSMutableDictionary *cellLayoutInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

     NSInteger sectionCount = [self.collectionView numberOfSections];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

     for(NSInteger section = 0; section < sectionCount; section++) {
         NSInteger itemCount = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];

         for(NSInteger item = 0; item < itemCount; item++) {
             indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];

             UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
             itemAttributes.frame = [self frameForPadAtIndexPath:indexPath];

             cellLayoutInfo[indexPath] = itemAttributes;
         }
     }
     newLayoutInfo[kPadLayoutType] = cellLayoutInfo;
     self.layoutInfo = newLayoutInfo;
 }

 - (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
 {
     return self.collectionView.frame.size;
 }

 - (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
     NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.layoutInfo.count];

     [self.layoutInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *elementIdentifier,
                                                     NSDictionary *elementsInfo,
                                                     BOOL *stop) {
         [elementsInfo enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *indexPath,
                                                      UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes,
                                                      BOOL *innerStop) {
             if(CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, attributes.frame)) {
                 [allAttributes addObject:attributes];
             }
         }];
     }];
     return allAttributes;
 }

 - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     return self.layoutInfo[kPadLayoutType][indexPath];
 }

 # pragma mark _____Private

 - (CGRect)frameForPadAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     NSInteger row = indexPath.section/ self.numberOfColumns;
     NSInteger column = indexPath.section % self.numberOfColumns;

     CGFloat spacingX = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width - self.itemInsets.left - self.itemInsets.right - (self.numberOfColumns * self.itemSize.width);

     if(self.numberOfColumns > 1) spacingX = spacingX / (self.numberOfColumns - 1);

     CGFloat originX = floorf(self.itemInsets.left + (self.itemSize.width + spacingX) * column);

     CGFloat originY = floor(self.itemInsets.top + (self.itemSize.height + self.interItemSpacingY) * row);

     return CGRectMake(originX, originY, self.itemSize.width, self.itemSize.height);
 }
```

I invalidate the layout in each setter.

I am using a collectionView within my UIViewController
In the viewController I register my Cell class for use in viewDidLoad and setup the following:

```
 # pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     return 16;
 }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
 {
     return 1;
 }

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     Pad *myPad = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kPadLayoutType forIndexPath:indexPath];
     return myPad;
 }
```

Comment: Show some code, might help to track the problem down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me your `frameForPadAtIndexPath:` method would return the same frame for each item within the same section and only varies the position with the section.

Changing

```
 NSInteger row = indexPath.section/ self.numberOfColumns;
 NSInteger column = indexPath.section % self.numberOfColumns;
```

into

```
 NSInteger row = indexPath.item/ self.numberOfColumns;
 NSInteger column = indexPath.item % self.numberOfColumns;
```

might give you better results.